# Generic ILogger, or through Serilog, add logged property

Tags: .net, logging, serilog

Is there a way to add properties to a given instance of ILogger? (from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions). I am using Serilog and usually injecting ILogger instances into constructors. So it could also be a solution that leverages some Serilog APIs.

I am aware of `ILogger.BeginScope` and `LogContext.PushProperty` but these simply add information to the current Async context. I would like to add information to the instance of the logger itself, so that any log produced by that logger has the extra properties.

What I would like to achieve is similar to:

```cs
class Foo {
  private ILogger logger;
  public Foo(ILogger logger) {
     logger.AddProperty("Property", "value"); // now every calls using that logger have that extra prop
     _logger = logger;
  }

  public void Dummy() => _logger.LogDebug("logging something..."); // this log event would have the Property=value added to it automatically
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Update 2021-08-21: You can now use [Serilog.Enrichers.GlobalLogContext](https://github.com/augustoproiete/serilog-enrichers-globallogcontext)

Install the [Serilog.Enrichers.GlobalLogContext](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Enrichers.GlobalLogContext/) package from NuGet:

```
Install-Package Serilog.Enrichers.GlobalLogContext
```

Add the Serilog namespaces to your C# file:

```cs
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Context;
```

Include the global log context enricher in your logger configuration:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromGlobalLogContext()
    // ... other configuration ...
    .CreateLogger();
```

The `FromGlobalLogContext()` enricher dynamically adds properties present in the `Serilog.Context.GlobalLogContext`, to *all* produced events in your application.

Then, properties can be added and removed from the global log context using `GlobalLogContext.PushProperty()`:

```cs
GlobalLogContext.PushProperty("AppVersion", GetThisAppVersion());
GlobalLogContext.PushProperty("OperatingSystem", GetCurrentOS());
```

After the code above is executed, any log event written to any Serilog sink will carry the properties `AppVersion` and `OperatingSystem` automatically.

Source: https://github.com/augustoproiete/serilog-enrichers-globallogcontext

---

##### Original answer

One way to achieve that, would be to create a custom [Serilog Enricher](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment) that you hook up to the Serilog logging pipeline at the start, that you can also access throughout your application (ideally via dependency injection).

This enricher would provide you with a way to add new properties, and it would be responsible in making sure that the properties are applied to all log events.

The example below is a simplified version of this idea (**definitely not recommended for production use as-is**, but rather as pseudo-code to show the basics of how the main pieces fit together):

```
// WARNING: This is *NOT* Production code :)

public sealed class GlobalPropertyEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    // TODO: Make it thread-safe
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, object> _properties =
        new Dictionary<string, object>();

    private static readonly Lazy<GlobalPropertyEnricher> _instance =
        new Lazy<GlobalPropertyEnricher>(() => new GlobalPropertyEnricher());

    public static GlobalPropertyEnricher Instance => _instance.Value;

    private GlobalPropertyEnricher()
    {
    }

    public static void SetProperty(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        // TODO: Make it thread-safe
        _properties[propertyName] = value;
    }

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        // TODO: Make it thread-safe
        // TODO: Properties should be cached (instead of CreateProperty) every time

        foreach (var p in _properties)
        {
            var property = propertyFactory.CreateProperty(p.Key, p.Value);
            logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(property);
        }
    }
}
```

NB: For the purposes of this example, I have a static class accessible globally through your app, but you prob. would have that registered as a [singleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#singleton) instance in your DI container.

With the enricher example above, you can add/replace properties from anywhere via `GlobalPropertyEnricher.SetProperty`. e.g.

```
GlobalPropertyEnricher.SetProperty("Name", "Augusto");
GlobalPropertyEnricher.SetProperty("Year", DateTime.UtcNow.Year);
```

Finally, when you include the enricher in the Serilog pipeline, all the properties you set will be added to every event log message you write anywhere in the app:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.With(GlobalPropertyEnricher.Instance)
    .WriteTo.(...)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Augusto I wasn't expecting such a detailed answer.
The explanation is crystal clear. I'll try to do a nuget package out of it, may benefit other folks

Comment: @Fabien I eventually needed to use this on a project and ended up writing a small nuget package with an improved implementation and API: [Serilog.Enrichers.GlobalLogContext](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Enrichers.GlobalLogContext/)

Comment: Good answer and good work with nuget. A little bit unfortunate that that enricher works only globally and you can't set properties per logger instance to use it for distributed logging.

Comment: @cassandrad Cheers. Interesting idea. Because Enrichers are not sink-specific, I imagine we'd need to use sub-loggers to be able to separate the pipelines. I created an [issue](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-enrichers-globallogcontext/issues/2) on the repo to track and discuss possible ideas.