# Serilog AspnetCore - not capturing Additional Column data

Tags: .net, .net-core, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

I configured Serilog in a dotNet app to capture an extra column of data but nothing shows up in log. I'm passing 'elapsedTime' as an extra parameter to _logger.Information(), but nothing shows up in the log table for ElapsedMilliseconds. Any ideas what I missed?

**Program.cs**

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
                connectionString: Config.CONN_STRING_PROD,
                tableName: "APP_SERILOG",
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information,
                columnOptions: GetSqlColumnOptions()
            )
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    private static ColumnOptions GetSqlColumnOptions()
    {
        var options = new ColumnOptions();

        options.AdditionalColumns = new Collection<SqlColumn>
        {
            new SqlColumn
            {
                ColumnName = "ElapsedMilliseconds",
                AllowNull = true,
                DataType = SqlDbType.Int
            }
        };

        return options;
    }
```

**ReportLoggingExtensions.cs**

```
public static class ReportLoggingExtensions
{
    public static Serilog.ILogger _logger { get; } = Log.Logger;

    public static void LogSqlResponceInformation(string sqlCmd, int recordCount, TimeSpan elapsedTime)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> logMessage = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Sql Responce - ", sqlCmd },
            { "Result record count", recordCount.ToString() },
            { "Execution Time", elapsedTime.ToString() }
        };

        _logger.Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logMessage), elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

**Log Table:**

```
select top 1 *
from APP_SERILOG
order by Id desc

Id  Message Level   TimeStamp   Exception   LogEvent    ElapsedMilliseconds
1059381 {"Sql Responce - ":"RiderActivity","Result record count":"0","Execution Time":"00:00:00.1455455"}   2023-06-27 16:28:44.557 NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Trying variations:
ForContext is suppose to help when attempting to log information to extra columns, but still no success.

```
         _logger
             .ForContext("ElapsedMilliseconds", elapsedTime)
             .ForContext("LogId", 1)
             .Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logMessage));
```

Also tried:

```
            using (LogContext.PushProperty("ElapsedMilliseconds", elapsedTime))
            using (LogContext.PushProperty("LogId", 1))
            {
                _log.Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logMessage));
            }
```

Comment: `_log.Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logMessage))` needs to be `_log.Information("{message"}, ....)` - first HAS to be a message template

Comment: JsonConvert.SerializeObject returns a string. How does that violate the message template.

Comment: The string can have braces in it for a start. But seriously, go look it up. It's worth reading the docs on at least that and eliminate basic errors like that so people can dig deeper once the basics are sorted

Comment: Or, putting it a different way: please go look it up. Not having that correct can lead to unexpected results. You've taken the time to pose a question about unexpected things you are seeing. https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following turned out to be useful works.

[Generic ILogger, or through Serilog, add logged property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65817012/generic-ilogger-or-through-serilog-add-logged-property)

Startup:

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Context;
using Serilog.Events;
using Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer;
. . .
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithMachineName()
    . . .
    .CreateLogger();
```

Runtime:

```
            GlobalLogContext.PushProperty("LogId", userId);
            GlobalLogContext.PushProperty("ElapsedMilliseconds", totalSeconds);
            _log.Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logMessage));
```

Comment: don't forget json is not a safe or correct message template..... Also if pushproperty is returning IDisposable, in general you want to dispose it when exiting that scope (omitting won't stop something from happening, of course; it's more about correctness)